# Query for frequency of e-mail addresses in a field

Tags: mysql, aggregate

Newbie here. I know the answer is out there, but lack the vocabulary to ask the right question...

I am looking for a MYSQL query which gives me the frequency of addresses in the field emailaddress. I would like to know how many are unique, how many occur twice, three times etc.

Comment: some terms that come to mind for a search would be:  `GROUP BY`, `COUNT`, `SELECT`.   For instance, https://duckduckgo.com/?q=mysql+group+by+count  Also you should add more detail to your question, such as the table structure, sample data, and desired output.

Comment: Since you self-identified as new to MySQL, and your questions is very basic, this question will likely get migrated to http://stackoverflow.com .  http://dba.stackexchange.com is more for advanced DBMS topics.

Comment: There's probably a duplicate of this but I can't find it.

Comment: `SELECT email, count(*) as occurence
FROM t
GROUP BY email
ORDER BY occurence DESC`

Answer (score 2):

I think you want a "count of counts", which can be done with 2 `GROUP BY`, once to find how many times an emailaddress has been used:

```
    SELECT emailaddress, COUNT(*) AS frequency
    FROM tablename
    GROUP BY emailaddress ;
```

and then enclosing the above in a derived table and doing another `GROUP BY` to find how many emailaddresses were used once, twice, thrice, etc...:

```
SELECT frequency, COUNT(*) AS emailadresses
FROM
  ( SELECT COUNT(*) AS frequency           -- we don't need email any more
    FROM tablename
    GROUP BY emailaddress
  ) AS x 
GROUP BY frequency ;
```

---

Minor mysql quirk. If you want:

```
GROUP BY frequency 
ORDER BY frequency DESC ;
```

it can be abbreviated (and it will be a bit more efficient) in MySQL as:

```
GROUP BY frequency DESC ;
```

Comment: Thank you! This was the query I used, but completed with ORDER BY frequency DESC from Mihai.

Comment: @mustema: See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

the ones that occurs once are of course unique, but if you want to count let's say all emails that occurs once, twice, thrice and so on, you might have to use a subquery as ypercube has explained.

`SELECT DISTINCT email, COUNT(email) FROM email_table GROUP BY email;`